# Keras running slow on AWS, TESLA V100

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, keras

I'm using aws p3.2xlarge with one Tesla V100 GPU, while training my model on my personal dataset I get lower performance than training the same model on my laptop.
Here are the performance measurments (ETA)

```
TESLA V100
36672/332910 [==>...........................] - ETA: 1:56 - loss: 0.5794 - acc: 0.6664

GTX 950M
36480/299679 [==>...........................] - ETA: 30s - loss: 0.5894 - acc: 0.6652
```

Current aws setup:

> Operating system:  Ubuntu
>
> CUDA version: Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
>
> Cudnn version:
>   7.2.1
>
> Tensorflow version:
>   1.10.0

Comment: I have had issues related to the use of CPU optimisations such as AVX instruction sets that some cloud machines don't use (I don't know about AWS). Could be worth looking into.

Comment: Also, the throughput of loading data into your GPU could slow things down on the AWS instance if your data set is big. Are you using a fast SSD, etc?

Comment: Can you check if GPU is really utilized and how much % of it's used? Command `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi`  Also do you use estimators API to train the model or feed_dict ?

Comment: @LaurentS I'm using general purpose SSD, but I don't have large data set. I'm using LSTM network which gets 15 inputs which are all floats. I do not believe it would have such an effect. Plus aws monitoring doesn't seem to show high SSD load.

Comment: @Vlad-HC Volatile GPU-Util shows 34% while training

Comment: @Vlad-HC To train, to Keras fit method I pass numpy array of size (30k, 10, 15).

Comment: Hi @ModestasJurčius, did you find the reason why this happens? I am getting same speed on K80 and V100 while training YoloV3 keras implementation on my dataset.